# ARM Template parameter is not working for custom payload json

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-yaml

In ARM template How we can parameterize the "customWebhookPayload" . I am trying to automate the deployment using azure pipeline and I am getting errors when I tried to parameterize the given "customWebhookPayload" json in parameters.json and and replacing those values with azurepipeline runtime parameters.

```
"schedule":"[parameters('schedule')]",
"action":{
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
    "severity": "[parameters('severity')]",
    "aznsAction":{
        "customWebhookPayload": "{ \"AlertRuleName\":\"#alertrulename\", \"AlertType\":\"#alerttype\", \"Severity\":\"#severity\", \"Application\":\"#{appname}#\", \"Text\":\"#alertrulename fired with #searchresultcount records.Rate limit applied on #{appname}# API Management was triggered\", \"SearchQuery\":\"#searchquery\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40167) GitHub document will help you parameterise the "customWebhookPayload". You need to create the variable of object type for custom Webhook JSON and then convert it to String while referring it in the Resources part of the template.

As for to automate the deployment using azure pipeline, I'm not sure if we can achieve it. But as a work around you can try using the [FileTransform Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) of Azure Pipelines for variable substitution. We can use this task to apply file transformations and **variable substitutions on configuration and parameters files**.

I would suggest to read this [JSON variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#jsonvarsubs) for more information.